Flutter evaluateJavascript Not working for me
await webViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: """
    \$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
      if(\$("a[href^='/GenericUpload/GetFile']").length > 0){

    \$("a[href^='/GenericUpload/GetFile']").off('click').on('click', function (){ window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('MobileAppDownload',\$(this).attr('href')); });
      }}); """);

This code find a button in my app and execute my action. this code work once and after that not working. MUST uninstall app or clear data and cache in android to work again. this code work in IOS normally.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Not sure if this is your problem, but DOMSubtreeModified has been deprecated long ago.

You can use MutationObserver to Observe changes only within the specific container or element where the button is expected to appear. This reduces the number of observed nodes and improves performance
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up resources (e.g., disconnect observers)
    if (_webViewController != null) {
      _webViewController!.clearCache(); 
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('your_web_page_url')),
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _webViewController = controller;
        },
        onPageFinished: (controller, url) async {
          await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            const targetNode = document.querySelector('#your-target-container'); // Replace with the actual container ID
            const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

            const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
              mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                  const button = document.querySelector("a[href^='/GenericUpload/GetFile']");
                  if (button) {
                    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                      window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('MobileAppDownload', button.getAttribute('href'));
                    });
                    observer.disconnect(); // Stop observing after the button is found
                  }
                }
              });
            });

            if (targetNode) {
              observer.observe(targetNode, config);
            }
          """);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

